# Does printf convert a binary number into its decimal form?

Tags: c, binary, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define N_BITS 16

int16_t sixteen_in(char *bits);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        printf("%d\n", sixteen_in(argv[arg]));
    }

    return 0;
}

// given a strings of binary digits ('1' and '0')
// return corresponding signed 16 bit integer

int16_t sixteen_in(char *bits) {
    assert(strlen(bits) == N_BITS);
    int16_t result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_BITS; i++) {
        if (bits[i] == '1') {
            result |= 1 << (N_BITS - i - 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

From my understanding, the sixteen_in(char *bits) function will return a 'result' that is the int16_t binary representation of the string that is passed in.
So, if the string '01001' is passed into the sixteen_in function, the 'result' will be 01001 in int_16 form.

However, whenever I run the program for say '01001', the output is 9, which I understand is the decimal form of 01001.

So, my question is, where in the program does this conversion from 01001 in int16_t form into 9 occur. I am presuming it is performed by the printf in main because that is where the function is being called.

Some insight into this would be so appreciated :))

Output is in decimal form, however, I do not understand where the conversion from int16_t binary representation into decimal occurs.

Comment: Internally values are always represented in binary. `printf` converts it to a decimal textual representation (due to the `%d` specifier).

Comment: If this is built with NDEBUG defined, then the input string `01001` should give a failed assertion. If NDEBUG is not defined, this input string will access the input array beyond its bounds which gives undefined behavior.

Comment: To elaborate on wholstad's comment: suppose you have `uint8_t n = 42`. (I'm using an 8 bit representation for brevity and to avoid having to talk about endianness, but all this basically holds the same for a uint16_t.) Internally, this is represented as 0101010.  printf("%d", n) will convert this to a sequence of characters. These are *also* in binary, but the binary representation of `'4', '2'` rather than `42`. For ASCII/UTF, this is 00110100 00110010.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion from the binary representation in `int16_t` form to the decimal form (like 9 in your example) occurs in the `printf` function.

Specifically, this line:

```c
// main.c:12
printf("%d\n", sixteen_in(argv[arg]));
```

In this line, `%d` is a conversion specification for printing an integer in decimal form. When you pass the result of `sixteen_in(argv[arg])` to `printf`, it takes the binary representation returned by `sixteen_in` and converts it to decimal form because of the `%d` format specifier and prints it. The `sixteen_in` function correctly converts the binary string to an `int16_t` binary representation, but the conversion to decimal form occurs when you print the result using `printf` with the `%d` conversion specification.

The sort of conversion occurs on the following line

The function processes each bit of the input binary string, checks if it's '1', and sets the corresponding bit in the result variable to '1' accordingly.

```c
result |= 1 << (N_BITS - i - 1);
```

**EDIT:**

The printf function does indeed convert the number while printing it. Here's some source:

> The char, short, int, long, or long long argument is printed as a decimal (base 10) integer. If the argument is signed, it will be printed as a signed value. If the argument is unsigned, it will be printed as an unsigned value. This conversion has the same meaning as i.

Comment: Re “**prints**, not *convert*”: The C standard calls `%d` a conversion specification. The standard’s specification of the `printf` function, by way of the `fprintf` clause, says the format “specifies how subsequent arguments are converted for output”. The operation `fprintf` performs is a conversion with printing. For `%d`, an `int` value is converted from binary to a decimal numeral in a string of characters, which is printed. The value is converted: `printf` takes a representation of a value in one form and produces a representation of the same value in a different form.

Comment: @EricPostpischil

> and prints, not convert,

as I stated here

Comment: The issue is not that `printf` does not print; it does. The issue is this answer states it “prints, not convert”. That is incorrect. It does convert. It converts and prints, and people learning about C should not be told that `printf` does not convert. It does not print the raw bytes of an `int`. It converts them to another form.

Comment: I'm sorry, thanks for the clarification :)